# Terminate subscription on external event

Tags: java, spring, project-reactor

In an application, I use long polling to an external HTTP endpoint. I do this using Spring's reactive `WebClient`. In order to cleanly shutdown when the application stops (and avoid ugly Netty stack traces), I use `takeUntil()` with an instance of an `EmitterProcessor` that I call `onNext()` on when Spring stops my bean (I implement `SmartLifecycle`).

The whole thing works something like this:

```
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
public class LongPollingMessageReceiver implements SmartLifecycle {
    private boolean running = true;

    private final EmitterProcessor<Boolean> shutdown = EmitterProcessor.create();

    private final BackendMessageReceiver backendMessageReceiver;

    public void waitForMessages() {
        Mono.defer(() -> backendMessageReceiver.receiveMessages()) // Calls WebClient
            .repeat()
            .takeUntilOther(shutdown)
            .subscribe(event -> {
                // do something when the http endpoint answers
            });
    }

    @Override
    public int getPhase() {
        // We need to cancel the subscriptions before Reactor/Netty shuts down.
        // Using @PreDestroy does not work because it is called *after* the Reactor/Netty shutdown.
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void start() {
        // Not needed
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() {
        log.info("Stopping message subscriptions");
        shutdown.onNext(true);
        shutdown.onComplete();
        running = false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isRunning() {
        return running;
    }
}
```

The whole mechanism works fine for now. However, `EmitterProcessor` is marked as `@Deprecated` and the javadoc says to use a `Sink` instead. `Sink` does not implement the `Publisher` interface and thus can not be passed into `takeUntilOther()`.

What am I supposed to do to solve this problem without being stuck on Project Reactor < 3.5 forever?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Sinks` are intended as the developer-facing API for programmatically triggering reactive events. This wouldn't be very useful if there wasn't a way to present these as a typical `Flux` or `Mono` to the rest of the application though.

`Sinks.Many` has an `asFlux()` view to that effect. Similarly, `Sinks.One` and `Sinks.Empty` have an `asMono()` view.

That's what you can use to pass to `takeUntilOther`.